# Javascript ES6 eliminate usage of 'this' keyword everywhere in classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, traceur

I am using Traceur to be able to write some javascript of the future right now and this is a function that I have in some class

```
create() {
    this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    this.segmentcache = new SegmentCache(this.game);
    this.segments = new Segments(this.game);
    this.segments.cache = this.segmentcache;
    this.segments.seek(3);

    this.guy = new Guy(this.game, 140 + 8, 80);
    this.guy.anchor.set(0.5, 1.0);
    this.game.add.existing(this.guy);

    this.game.camera.x = 100;
    this.ticks = 0;
    this.cross = 0;
}
```

Of course, as with any traditional javascript code, it is covered with the this keyword all over the place. Coming from Java and the likes, it is very unnatural for me to have to specify this when referring to a field inside of a class when I don't have to.

Is there any way of getting Traceur to interpret classes the same way as Java? (i.e auto insert this when not specified, etc.)

Comment: That would not be valid JavaScript anymore. Traceur does not define a new language, it sticks to the ES6 spec. I don't think you are approaching this correctly. If you want to write JavaScript than do that, and don't try to treat it like Java (because it's very different anyway). For me it's exactly the other way round: I find it very confusing that you don't have to specify `this` in Java. I find this "implicitness" makes it more difficult to follow the code.

Comment: `function() { with(this) { ... } }` ;)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - I almost missed the winky at the end. Would serve him right though.

Comment: More seriously: this is probably not possible to implement efficiently in a language as dynamic as JavaScript. It might be possible to implement in the 'SoundScript' subset that is being proposed, but that's several steps beyond ES6. Maybe one day.

Comment: I don't believe it would be a good idea. If you want to write Java, write Java. Perhaps compile it down to Javascript. But don't force the language to be something it isn't.

Comment: you can move them into a literal and merge them, but you'de have to be careful about re-using names as you go along, like `this.segmentcache` for example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, no.

In Java, C#, C++, etc. this is a feature of compiler, not execution. This means it is done implicitly and what the compiler does is putting correct address into `this` and referencing variables in a correct way. There is a rule in most compilers that if you have a local variable (in local scope) with same name it has precedence of member variables.

While in javascript you can easily substitute `this` via `call`, `apply` or `bind` and have your function being called *over* an object which the author didn't intend to work with (i.e. `this` may be an object with different structure). And I think this is the reason why the language syntax requires from you to always explicitly specify if you're referring scope or `this`.

More in javascript function body actually can read global scope, so defining `window.member` (if in browser) may change the behavior of you functions if you don't use explicit `this`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such feature in ES6.

This type of feature would be complicated by the fact that Javascript allows referencing variables in the parent scope.  So, it would have to somehow discern whether a line of code like:

```
ticks = 0;
```

means

```
this.ticks = 0;
```

or whether it means to reference a variable in the current or parent scope by the name of `ticks`.

The mere adding of a property to an object could mess up code that was working just fine before by creating a conflict between a property reference and a local variable or parent scoped variable of the same name.  That would likely be a mess.  Now, you'd have to name scope your local variables just to avoid ever having a conflict with a property name.  And, if you're having to scope local variables, you've just reintroduced an extra piece of syntax that you were trying to get rid of.

Java can tolerate this because the compiler knows, in advance, all property names so it can report an error if there is a conflict.   Javascript allows dynamically added properties (added at any time) so the parser does not really have any idea what property names will or will not be on any given object at parse time so it can't warn about conflicts.  This is just an inherent difference in how the languages parse/compile and work and thus leads to some different capabilities or requirements in expressing the code.

It is possible to use the `with` structure to avoid some typing, but `with` is being removed from Javascript (not permitted in strict mode) for reasons detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses), not enhanced, so not a recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

As an unsophisticated illustration what might be possible, you can preprocess your classes to insert `this.` for a predefined set of property names, e.g. via custom static meta configuration for each class, that is available to a `gulp` build file.

```
DEBUG ClassPreprocessor: buildSync [ 'logger',
  'context',
  'config',
  'startedComponents',
  'components',
  'requiredComponents' ] 
regex ([^a-z\.'])(logger|context|config|startedComponents|components|requiredComponents)([^a-z:'])
replaceWith $1this.$2$3
```

where from the specified prop names, for now i'm constructing a regex to preprocess the class. This is terribly fragile though, since it's not token based. Later, I'd like to try something similar via a Babel transformer on the AST.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid having to type `this` when you're assigning instance variables in the constructor (or anywhere, really), you can use `_.extend()`

```
// this, this, this
this.a = true;
this.b = 2;
this.c = "three";

// becomes...
_.extend(this, {
  a: true,
  b: 2,
  c: "three"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Many recommend using a function instead (put inside a module in my example) of class to avoid `this` keyword, but it then you will have to use `function` keyword as well as `let` or `var` in front of every property. So you will have to decide which one you like best.

```
export function createPerson {
  var name;

  function setName(nameParam) {
     name = nameParam;
     doStuff();
  }

  function doStuff() {
    //...
  }

  return {
    setName, doStuff
  }
}
```

Since you also have to return the functions you want to be reachable for the "instance" , it could feel more cluttered in total over a class. Also since you don't use this keyword you would have to use different names for parameters than your properties. Many people prefer this then as it is clear what you are referring to and it is less probable you will refer to the wrong property or function.